# How to get parent object property in child

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I have a javascript object like below:

```
{
 type: "ul",
 id: "1",
 children: [
  {
   type: "li",
   id: "2",
   children: [
    {
      type: "ul",
      id: "3",
      children: [...]
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

I want to turn it into:

```
{
 type: "ul",
 id: "1",
 children: [
  {
   type: "li",
   id: "2",
   parentId: "1",
   children: [
    {
      type: "ul",
      id: "3",
      parentId: "2",
      children: [...]
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

There can be infinite nesting in the children's array and it should add parentId to only who have a parent and stop if the children's array is empty or the key doesn't exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a recursive solution:

```js
const obj={type:"ul",id:"1",children:[{type:"li",id:"2",children:[{type:"ul",id:"3"}]}]};

function setIds(obj, parent) {
    if (parent) {
      obj.parentId = parent.id;
    }
    obj?.children?.forEach(e => setIds(e, obj))
}

setIds(obj)
console.log(obj)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height: 100%!important}
```

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't be any more complex than

```
const parentify = (parent, parentId) => ({
  ...parent,
  parentId,
  children: parent.children.map( child => parentify(child, parent.id ) ),
});
```

Kick it off with:

```
const newObject = parentify( originalObject ) ;
```

Comment: Perhaps `...(parentId == null ? {} : {parentId},` to handle the missing id at the root level.

Comment: @ScottSauyet — `parentId` will be undefined at the root level, meaning that, unless the root-level call specifies some special value for `parentId`, the root-level object will get `parentId: undefined`. Serialized to JSON, that would mean that the root-level object is missing its `parentId` property.

Comment: Right.  I was just noting the requirement, "it should add parentId to only who have a parent".  I personally prefer to choose `null` in such cases.  There's nothing wrong with `undefined`, but it is distinguishable from not existing in various ways (unless, as you note, it's serialized into JSON.)